# OpenGL ES VBO strange memory impact

Tags: android, opengl-es, out-of-memory, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I'm running into out of memory exceptions in device log generated by GPU when trying to load heavy graphics scene using VBO on Android.

```
20:53:48.640 app W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpumem_alloc_id:2255>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
20:53:48.642 app E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:1971>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
```

Raw binary data size i'm trying to supply is less than half of available amount of RAM. After doing some research, i found that after each `glBufferData(..)` call the amount of free memory decreases 2 times the size of data supplied (tried on different devices, same result). Here is my setup:

```
        logMem("before buff creation");

        ByteBuffer dummyBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024 * 1024 * 16).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        byte[] some = new byte[1024];
        for (int i = 0; i < dummyBuff.capacity(); i+= some.length) {
            dummyBuff.put(some);
        }

        dummyBuff.rewind();

        logMem("buff data created");

        int[] bufferHandles = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, bufferHandles, 0);
        int bufferHandle = bufferHandles[0];

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandle);
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dummyBuff.capacity(), dummyBuff, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        logMem("buff data supplied");
```

Amount of memory left is logged with

```
    manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService( Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    info = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();

    ...
    manager.getMemoryInfo(info);
    Log.v("mem", tag + ", mem " + info.availMem/1024/1024);
```

Here is what i am getting in the log

```
20:13:34.243 V/mem:  before buff creation, mem 1381
20:13:34.466 V/mem:  buff data created, mem 1366
20:13:34.500 V/mem:  buff data supplied, mem 1334
```

I also tried a combination of

```
        GLES20.glBufferData(.., dummyBuf.capacity(), null, ..);
        GLES20.glBufferSubData(.., 0, dummyBuf.capacity(), dummyBuf);
```

In this case after first line execution i was getting a loss of 1x buffer size, as expected, but with the second, another 1x buffer size of memory was gone. 
I tried it on 2 different devices utilizing different GPUs (Adreno, Mali) and was getting same behavior. So, my question is: am i missing something, or is this an expected behavior? Is there any way to decrease this RAM impact when supplying data to VBO?

Answer (score 1):

Are you remembering to free the copy of the buffer you allocated?

In OpenGL ES all GPU server-side resources (textures, buffers, programs, etc) are copied into memory owned by the driver stack. Drivers can't just keep pointers to the buffers allocated by the application.

Once you have uploaded the data you can safely delete the application-side copy; it's not needed any more.

Comment: Well, that was the first thing i double checked, and yes, i'm sure that this data is not stored anymore - when triggering GC collection manually in debug, i could observe it being reclaimed. As you may see from the log, total impact on memory for my code was 3 times the size of my data, but triggering GC did trim it to 2 times.

Comment: Remember most processes will cache page allocations in user-space for performance reasons. If `availMem` is just reporting the free page count from the kernel the it's oblivious to any "free" pages which are held in user-space page pools (e.g. in the driver or in the VM heap manager); garbage collection in the GC doesn't necessarily force all free pages to be returned to the operating system.

Comment: Hmm..caching sounds reasonable, still, for the nature of data i'm supplying (GL_STATIC_DRAW), i'd expect the driver to release memory used for caching as soon as it's transfered to GPU space (in a reasonable time), but it seems like it never happens. Just to be sure that it's not a java issue, i tried same code with JNI, obtaining same result. Interestingly, though, in a third device, Samsung Galaxy S7 had totally different behavior, the memory track had zero corellation with the amount of data i was supplying.